# Why is \subsection undefined when using \titleformat?

Tags: errors

I'm using TexLive and Sublime Text 3 with TexTools. When compiling

```
\title{my title}
\author{
        Foo Men
}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Small\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

it compiles and a pdf is generated which looks fine, but I'm also getting:
`foo.tex:18: Undefined control sequence. [\subsection{subsection}]`

Without the
 `\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Small\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]`

everything is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The undefined command is not `\subsection` but `\Small`. There is not a command `\Small` but `\small`. Note, TeX is case sensitive. So

```
\title{my title}
\author{
        Foo Men
}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\small% Changed!
  \bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

works.

BTW: I would recommend to set all information like `\title`, `\author` and `\date` at least after `\documentclass`, because some classes may handle them different than the LaTeX kernel. So I would use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{my title}
\author{
        Foo Men
}
\date{\today}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\small% Changed!
  \bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

or even

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\small% Changed!
  \bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}
\title{my title}
\author{
        Foo Men
}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{Section}
\subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I though I did sorry. Misclicked.